# How to communicate between two lightsail instances in a same zone?

Tags: amazon-vpc, amazon-lightsail

I have two instances like instance a [using wordpress] and instance b [using windows server 2016] on Amazon Lightsail.One website is running through instance a. At instance b i have installed Geoserver and added some vector layers. Now i want to access these layers from instance a. How will i do it?

Comment: Have you tried accessing b from a using b's private IP address?  That should be all you need to do.  Lightsail instances should already be able to access each other.

Comment: Thank you Michael . Actually I want to know the steps to access data from one instance to other of Amazon Lightsail using private IP. Please tell me steps